# Defining and Removing Spring Boot / Spring JPA Datasources Programmatically at Runtime?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I need to create Spring Boot Datasources dynamically at runtime.  Anyone know how to do this.  Effectively I need to do this on demand:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb1;
    username: sa
    password:
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    platform: h2

spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb2;
    username: sa
    password:
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    platform: h2
```

...

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdbN;
    username: sa
    password:
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    platform: h2
```

Thoughts?

Comment: See comments on [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41373968/no-persistence-provider-for-entitymanager-named#comment69951793_41373968) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41352624/dynamically-updating-entitymanager-in-spring-boot-jpa#comment69916547_41352624).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below way to create data-source programmatically

```
DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:testdb1");
dataSource.setUsername("sa");
dataSource.setPassword("");
dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
```